# Unexpected cartesian product in Foxpro SQL statement

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I am executing the following Visual FoxPro SQL statement from a C# program. I am expecting to get 1 result but I am not getting any results.

```
SELECT 
    iplclaim.lc_lname, ipcname.cn_lname, ipcbusn.cb_bname   ;
FROM 
    iplclaim  ;
INNER JOIN 
    iplclsub ON iplclsub.ls_claimno + iplclsub.ls_sclaimno = iplclaim.lc_claimno + 'A' ;
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ipcname ON ipcname.cn_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno  ;
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ipcbusn ON ipcbusn.cb_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno  ;
WHERE 
    iplclaim.lc_claimno = '  1105'     ;
    AND NOT DELETED()
```

I am able to reproduce the problem running from VFP using the following program...

```
CLOSE DATABASES all
OPEN DATABASE ipcust.dbc
USE C:\TESTVFP\IPS\DATA\PPDATA\IPlclaim IN 0
USE C:\TESTVFP\IPS\DATA\PPDATA\iplclsub IN 0
USE C:\TESTVFP\IPS\DATA\PPDATA\IPcname IN 0
USE C:\TESTVFP\IPS\DATA\PPDATA\IPcbusn IN 0
SYS(3054,12)

SELECT iplclaim.lc_lname, ipcname.cn_lname, ipcbusn.cb_bname   ;
 FROM iplclaim  ;
INNER JOIN iplclsub ON iplclsub.ls_claimno + iplclsub.ls_sclaimno = '  1105A'     ;
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcname ON ipcname.cn_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno  ;
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcbusn ON ipcbusn.cb_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno  ;
WHERE iplclaim.lc_claimno = '  1105' ;
  AND NOT DELETED()
```

It seems that if the tables are not open before the program is executed the results are zero records.  If I open the tables and only execute the SQL statement it returns the expected one record.

The other thing that I would not expect is that when I run the program above, the SYS(3054,12) returns the following results (Notice the "Cartesian product")...

```
SELECT ipcname.cn_lname, ipcbusn.cb_bname FROM iplclsub LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcname ON ipcname.cn_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcbusn ON ipcbusn.cb_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno WHERE  iplclsub.ls_claimno + iplclsub.ls_sclaimno = '  1105A' AND NOT ip
Using index tag Claimall to rushmore optimize table iplclsub
Rushmore optimization level for table iplclsub: partial
Rushmore optimization level for table ipcname: none
Rushmore optimization level for table ipcbusn: none
Joining table iplclsub and table ipcname (Cartesian product)
Joining intermediate result and table ipcbusn (Cartesian product)
```

But when I run the SQL statement on its own with the tables already open the output looks different (notice no "Cartisian product")

```
SELECT ipcname.cn_lname, ipcbusn.cb_bname FROM iplclsub LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcname ON ipcname.cn_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcbusn ON ipcbusn.cb_inqno = iplclsub.ls_inqno WHERE  iplclsub.ls_claimno + iplclsub.ls_sclaimno = '  1105A' AND NOT ip
Using index tag Claimall to rushmore optimize table iplclsub
Rushmore optimization level for table iplclsub: partial
Rushmore optimization level for table ipcname: none
Rushmore optimization level for table ipcbusn: none
Joining table iplclsub and table ipcname using tag Inqno
Joining intermediate result and table ipcbusn using tag Inqno
```

Final Note:
There is only one record in iplclaim that matches the `WHERE` clause.  There is only one record in iplclsub that matches the `INNER JOIN iplclsub ON` clause.  There is only one record in ipcname that matches the `LEFT OUTER JOIN ipcname ON` clause and there is no record in ipcbusn that matches the `LEFT OUTER JOIN ipbusn ON` clause.

Can anybody explain what is causing this problem and what I have to do to resolve it?

**EDIT:**

Well I figured out the problem is the `AND NOT DELETED()`.  If I remove that clause everything works as expected.  Can someone explain that and can anybody tell me an alternative way to exclude deleted records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a warning in the FoxPro documentation about the SELECT-SQL command possibly returning unexpected results when using functions like DELETED() in multiple table queries.

The `SET DELETED ON` command can be used to ignore records that are marked for deletion.  With that option turned on it looks like the use of the DELETED() function could be removed from the query.

For the C# code, assuming you're using an OLEDB connection, the `SET DELETED ON` command can be executed on the same open FoxPro connection prior to executing the query.